# How to insert a image next to an input field - HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert an  image next to an input box. 
Here's what I am doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/a4aME/2307/

Basically,

```css
.iconCamera {
  background: url('https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials/images/coding_ground_home.jpg') no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="A" style="display:inline-block">
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Key">
    <div class="iconCamera"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since, I've given the `inline-block`, the two components should be displayed `side by side - in one line` right ?

But currently there are `stacked` one below other. Any pointers on what needs to be done on this case?

Comment: You didn't give `.iconCamera` an inline or inline-block display property and divs are block level by default

Comment: @j08691: Since, I apply a style to a `parent div` , that style should be inherited by its child, right ? Why are we required to separately specify a `inline-block` to a child element ?

Comment: Not all properties are inherited. Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display and scroll down the blue table (_"Inherited no"_). Be sure to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

Comment: I highly recommend to use a span for this problem instead of a div. A span has less semantic value. If your image is more valueable I'll suggest you add the image in your HTML instead of your CSS.

Comment: @j08691: Thank you.. It makes sense :)

Comment: @DennisSpierenburg: Changing `div` to `span` doesn't display the image at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` in the css specification.

http://jsfiddle.net/a4aME/2310/

```
.iconCamera {
    background: url('https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials/images/coding_ground_home.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Since, I apply a style to a parent div , that style should be inherited by its child, right ? Why are we required to separately specify a inline-block to a child element ?

Comment: I usually use specificity to declare style in this context.  So, you can use either the css provided or embed css inside the .iconCamera.  One other method can be to have a new rule tagged .A *  (anything inside the element of class A) to be inline-block.  Hope this helps.  j08691's comment provides a better answer as to why.   When in doubt I have resorted to specific style selectors.