# How can I place an image inside an input?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make an input field which is a search bar and I want to place a search icon on the left of the input field. I tried making this with setting the background-image property of the input field but it didn't work for me.
I've already read some other questions like this on Stackoverflow but these solutions didn't work for me.
I tried setting the display property of the input field as well but that didn't solve the problem for me.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <title>Google</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <a href="https://mail.google.com/">Gmail</a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/imghp?">Képek</a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/intl/hu/about/products?tab=ih"><img src="images/squares.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/intl/hu/about/products?tab=ih"><img class="profile" src="images/profile.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <a href=""><img src="images/google.gif" alt=""></a>
            <div id="sbcontainer">
                <div id="searchbar">
                    <input type="text"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

body {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
#header {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 15px 15px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    word-spacing: 10px;

}
.profile {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
a {
    display: inline;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#body {
    padding-top: 47px;
    text-align: center;
}
#searchbar {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
input {
    background: url(images/searchicon.png) no-repeat left center;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a image next to an input field - HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824806/how-to-insert-a-image-next-to-an-input-field-html)

Comment: no I already tried that out but even when I changed the display property of the input to inline it didn't do anything for me

Comment: however I want to place an image inside the input field and not next to that

Comment: @KristófGéró Your code is completely fine, the issue therefore probably lies in your image. Put the path in quotation marks and verify to begin with that your path is actually correct, you shouldn't see any issues in console

Answer (score 2):

With `background-image`. Your code is fine, your issue lies in your image path.

```css
input{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/50");
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

---

Here, the same exact thing but with your code.

```css
body {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
#header {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 15px 15px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    word-spacing: 10px;

}
.profile {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
a {
    display: inline;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#body {
    padding-top: 47px;
    text-align: center;
}
#searchbar {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
input {
    background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/30") no-repeat left center;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <a href="https://mail.google.com/">Gmail</a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/imghp?">Képek</a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/intl/hu/about/products?tab=ih"><img src="images/squares.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/intl/hu/about/products?tab=ih"><img class="profile" src="images/profile.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <a href=""><img src="images/google.gif" alt=""></a>
            <div id="sbcontainer">
                <div id="searchbar">
                    <input type="text"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and was able to put a picture of an apple to the left inside of the search bar, so im not sure what trouble you are having.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <title>Google</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <a href="https://mail.google.com/">Gmail</a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/imghp?">Képek</a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/intl/hu/about/products?tab=ih"><img src="images/squares.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="https://www.google.hu/intl/hu/about/products?tab=ih"><img class="profile" src="images/profile.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <a href=""><img src="images/google.gif" alt=""></a>
            <div id="sbcontainer">
                <div id="searchbar">
                    <input type="text"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```css
body {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
#header {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 15px 15px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    word-spacing: 10px;

}
.profile {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
a {
    display: inline;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#body {
    padding-top: 47px;
    text-align: center;
}
#searchbar {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
input {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgfZeQfcPa39Zodu_eXAUs9xYjmRk5lBry4TWh5nCWiWLf7dka-g&s) no-repeat left center;
    background-size: 20px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8jb0r7s/